# How to run selenium test cases in jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I had been introduced to concept of CI lately and was trying to work on jenkins CI. I was stuck up in one thing . How to trigger executable testng files in jenkins CI. For ex locally in our machines we just run testng.xml to execute couple of test cases. In the same way how can we trigger this xml file to run in jenkins CI ?

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by "run testing.xml" ?. How do you run it?. Could you give us the command?.

Comment: @Evgeniy : I use java to write selenium scripts.

Comment: @Morvader : testng.xml is the xml suite which consists of set of all test cases that i want to execute. We can create this testng.xml by using TestNg plugin in eclipse.

Comment: Do you use maven to build your project?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases with jenkins you wouldn't use an executable. Normally you'd run the wrapper for the tests (Junit/Nunit etc.) which Jenkins is fully capable of running on it's own.

Comment: can you give me an example for wrapper for the tests using Junit or Nunit ? Since my executable test cases will be in xml format can i trigger it in Jenkins ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this article to run TestNG tests using Maven: 
[Running TestNG tests using maven](http://wiki.collectionspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50167817)

After configuration is completed just add `Invoke top-level Maven targets` step to the Build Steps in Jenkins (Maven plugin should be installed). The target should be `test` in this case.

If you will face with any errors during configuration, try to google them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any build tool like maven or ant, you can invoke it from command line as we'll and specify your suite file.  Make sure to set the correct class paths http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng

You can put this as a build step in Jenkins.
Add a compilation step prior to this step.  I haven't ever tried it - have always used ant or maven, but that is where I would start exploring.